# Modifying memory/code segment of host application process in a Debugger on Windows

Tags: windows, debugging

I would like to modify the memory/code of the host application running in the IDE
while the application is running on windows 7 (using something like ptrace?)

My IDE is currently Eclipse

What methods can I use to do the same?